# Keep C# application running

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I'm building a Windows Service that uses FileSystemWatcher, and runs in the background.

I don't want to keep on uninstalling and installing the service every time I want to debug, so would like to do most of my development in a normal program before moving it into a service. But I'm quite new to this, and when I run it, it just runs through the block and exits.

What would be a good way to keep the program running?

Comment: To keep running indefinitely, a program typically needs a loop of some sort.

Comment: `while (true) {...}`, perhaps?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517550/wrapping-a-c-sharp-service-in-a-console-app-to-debug-it

Comment: Did any of this work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://einaregilsson.com/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/

I've used this before to debug my service as a Console application based on whether its running in an interactive user environment.

```
public partial class DemoService : ServiceBase
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DemoService service = new DemoService();

        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            service.OnStart(args);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop program");
            Console.Read();
            service.OnStop();
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(service);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I prefer `Console.ReadKey(true)` to avoid the blip of the typed character.

Comment: This what I do, but additionally also when in the console repeat logging output to the console which makes it easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true)
{
  // Execute your program's functionality here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a 7 part series a while ago titled: [Building a Windows Service](http://csharptest.net/837/building-a-windows-service-part-1-getting-started/).  It covers all the intricacies of building services, making them friendly to debug, and self-installing.

The basic feature set I was looking for was as follows:

- Building a service that can also be used from the console
- Proper event logging of service startup/shutdown and other activities
- Allowing multiple instances by using command-line arguments
- Self installation of service and event log
- Proper event logging of service exceptions and errors
- Controlling of start-up, shutdown and restart options
- Handling custom service commands, power, and session events
- Customizing service security and access control

The final result was a Visual Studio project template that creates a working service, complete with all of the above, in a single step.  It's been a great time saver for me.

see [Building a Windows Service – Part 7: Finishing touches](http://csharptest.net/990/building-a-windows-service-part-7-finishing-touches/) for a link to the project template and install instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s documentation from MSDN @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.80).aspx?ppud=4 . I have tried it before and it works under .NET Framework 3.x. I could not find my descriptive notes on it, at the moment.

Use the pragma #If DEBUG for debugging purposes like console outputs. Another is using the Debug object.

If you have any trouble with this, say so. I may be able to find my notes or make a Windows Service app myself, just to see if the steps on MSDN still work.