# Installing Windows Service without rebuilding

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

How can I install same windows service in different Service name as it has to point to a different database on the same machine.

Is there a way I can do without having to rebuild the project and change the name in Service installer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The service name is a string. You can pass it as a parameter to the installer and install the same service multiple times using the parameterized service name.

Here's an abstract base class we use for service that includes a code based installer.  You can adapt this to parameterized service name easily.

[Converting a c# commandline app to a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281819/converting-a-c-sharp-commandline-app-to-a-windows-service/12282179#12282179)

Comment: Well...isn't that nifty.  And here I was changing the name in the service and rebuilding.  I should have asked this question myself! ;)