# Thread started by windows service stops without error and yet it supposed to run an infinite loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, oracle, service

I am trying to create a windows service that calls a thread in a library. This is all in c#. The library has a function that reads from an oracle database, processes the data, stores it in a SQL Server database and updates the records in the oracle database. I run tests on this and saw that the loop runs about 80,000 times and then without throwing any errors (i even checked the event log) nothing happens. Please help with this 
This is the code

Windows Service

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        controller = new BillingController();
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(controller.dowork));
        thread.Start();
        AppLogs.LogtoFile("SmartCDRBillingService.log", string.Format("SmartCDRBillingService started successfully"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppLogs.LogtoFile("SmartCDRBillingService.log", string.Format("Start Service error:  {0}: {1}:", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.InnerException));
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public BillingController()
{
    AppConfig.LoadSettings();
}

public void dowork()
{
    try
    {
        BillingQueue nLogic = new BillingQueue();
        nLogic.QueueWorkItems();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log
        AppLogs.LogtoFile("BillingController.log", string.Format("dowork error:  {0}: {1}:", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.InnerException));
    }
}
```

Queue

```
public void QueueWorkItems()
{
    new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(doQueueWork)).Start();
}
private void doQueueWork()
{
    counter = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        counter++;
        List<EventUsageObject> eList = new List<EventUsageObject>();
        try
            {
                eList = _osqlcon.getallusageevents();
                if (eList.Count == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    ProcessUsageRequest(eList);//for Event Usage

                }                        
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log the error
                AppLogs.LogtoFile("BillingQueue.log", string.Format("doQueueWork error:  {0}: {1}:", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.InnerException));
            }
    }
}

public List<EventUsageObject> getallusageevents()
{
    List<EventUsageObject> recobjec = new List<EventUsageObject>();
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
    try
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = osql.getOracleConnectionString();
        conn.Open();              

        OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        string query = "SMART_DWH_OBJECT.GETALLEVENTSUSAGE";
        command.CommandText = query;
        OracleParameter myParameter = new OracleParameter("rc", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
        command.Parameters.Add("OUT_DATA", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            reader.FetchSize = 10000;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                    EventUsageObject info = new EventUsageObject();
                    info.CallStart = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["E_TIME"].ToString());
                    info.CallingMsisdn = reader["ACC_NBR"].ToString();
                    info.CalledMsisdn = reader["CALLED_MSISDN"].ToString();
                    info.Re_Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["RE_ID"].ToString());
                    info.EventName = reader["EVENT_NAME"].ToString();
                    info.Duration = Convert.ToInt32(reader["DURATION"].ToString());
                    info.Duration2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["DURATION2"].ToString());
                    info.Duration3 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["DURATION3"].ToString());
                    info.Duration4 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["DURATION4"].ToString());
                    info.Uplink = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UPLINK"].ToString());
                    info.Downlink = Convert.ToInt32(reader["DOWNLINK"].ToString());
                    info.PriceList = reader["PRICE_LIST"].ToString();
                    info.Cell_A = reader["CELL_A"].ToString();
                    info.Cell_B = reader["CELL_B"].ToString();
                    info.Acct_item_Type_Id1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ACCT_ITEM_TYPE_ID1"].ToString());
                    info.Acct_item_Type_Id2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ACCT_ITEM_TYPE_ID2"].ToString());
                    info.Acct_item_Type_Id3 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ACCT_ITEM_TYPE_ID3"].ToString());
                    info.Acct_item_Type_Id4 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ACCT_ITEM_TYPE_ID4"].ToString());
                    info.BalanceType1 = reader["BALANCE_TYPE1"].ToString();
                    info.BalanceType2 = reader["BALANCE_TYPE2"].ToString();
                    info.BalanceType3 = reader["BALANCE_TYPE3"].ToString();
                    info.BalanceType4 = reader["BALANCE_TYPE4"].ToString();
                    string d1 = reader["CHARGE1"].ToString();
                    string d2 = reader["CHARGE2"].ToString();
                    string d3 = reader["CHARGE3"].ToString();
                    string d4 = reader["CHARGE4"].ToString();
                    info.Charge1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CHARGE1"].ToString());
                    info.Charge2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CHARGE2"].ToString());
                    info.Charge3 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CHARGE3"].ToString());
                    info.Charge4 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CHARGE4"].ToString());
                   info.Prebalance1 = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_BALANCE1"].ToString());
                   info.Prebalance2 = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_BALANCE2"].ToString());
                   info.Prebalance3 = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_BALANCE3"].ToString());
                   info.Prebalance4 = Convert.ToDouble(reader["PRE_BALANCE4"].ToString());
                    info.Recstatus = 0;
                    recobjec.Add(info);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppLogs.LogtoFile("DBAPIError.log", string.Format("DBAPI error on getallusageevents error:  {0}: {1}:", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace));
    }
    return recobjec;
}



public void ProcessUsageRequest(List<EventUsageObject> list)
{
    try
    {
        //log the eventusage into the database.
        if (list.Count == 0)
            //do nothing
            return;
        else
            _mssqlcon.logEventUsage(list, _osqlcon);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppLogs.LogtoFile("BillingQueue.log", string.Format("ProcessUsageRequest error on loggingeventusage:  {0}: {1}:", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.InnerException));
    }
}


public void logEventUsage(List<EventUsageObject> ilist, DBAPI osql)
{
    int counter = 0;
    try
    {
        foreach (EventUsageObject log in ilist)
        {
            try
            {
                counter++;
                sql.executeNonQueryStoredProcedure("dbo.sp_dwh_eventusage", log.CallStart.ToString(), log.CallingMsisdn, log.CalledMsisdn, log.Re_Id.ToString(),
                                                              log.EventName.ToString(), log.Duration.ToString(), log.Duration2.ToString(), log.Duration3.ToString(),
                                                              log.Duration4.ToString(), log.Uplink.ToString(), log.Downlink.ToString(), log.PriceList, log.Cell_A,
                                                              log.Cell_B, log.Acct_item_Type_Id1.ToString(), log.Acct_item_Type_Id2.ToString(), log.Acct_item_Type_Id3.ToString(),
                                                              log.Acct_item_Type_Id4.ToString(), log.BalanceType1, log.Charge1.ToString(), log.BalanceType2, log.Charge2.ToString(),
                                                              log.BalanceType3, log.Charge3.ToString(), log.BalanceType4, log.Charge4.ToString(), log.Recstatus.ToString(), log.Prebalance1.ToString(),
                                                              log.Prebalance2.ToString(), log.Prebalance3.ToString(), log.Prebalance4.ToString());

                string query = "UPDATE dwh_ug_eventusage SET recstatus = 1" +
                        " WHERE E_TIME = TO_DATE('" + log.CallStart + "', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') AND ACC_NBR = '" + log.CallingMsisdn + "'";
                osql.executeNonQueryText(query);

                     AppLogs.LogtoFile("BillingQueue.log",
                string.Format("ProcesssubscriptionRequest has processed: {0}  record",
                log.Msisdn));
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Number == 2601)
                {
                    string query = "UPDATE dwh_ug_eventusage SET recstatus = 1" +
                        " WHERE E_TIME = TO_DATE('" + log.CallStart + "', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') AND ACC_NBR = '" + log.CallingMsisdn + "'";
                    osql.executeNonQueryText(query);                            
                }
                    AppLogs.LogtoFile("DBAPIError.log", string.Format("DBAPI error on logEventUsage:  {0}: {1}:",
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppLogs.LogtoFile("DBAPIError.log", string.Format("DBAPI error on logEventUsage:  {0}: {1}:",
            ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how `[java]` comes in this?  Should the answer be for Java?

Comment: may be the infinite loop is because of while (true) condition loop

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: The java tag was one of the auto added tags I did not see it and have removed it. This is c#

Comment: @psaraj12 It is supposed to run an infinite loop but the loop runs a few times and stops without giving any error

Comment: Are `doQueueWork` and `QueueWorkItems` actually meant to be the same thing? Also, how do you know how often it's actually looping?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever QueueWorkItems calls doQueueWork on a new thread. Also I was logging the number of times it run using a counter that I removed to keep the code clear or unimportant things

Comment: Try moving your `try`/`catch` inside `doQueueWork` to be outside of the `while` loop (make it cover the entire method) and see whether there's an actual error. It wasn't obvious before that there's code in there running in a different thread and not covered by any of your catch blocks - there might be an exception being throw that's therefore unhandled and tearing down the process.

Comment: So your `OnStart` creates a thread, which creates another thread, which does the work? Confusing, especially since that intermediate thread doesn't do anything. Also, you have several different log files you need to check for exceptions. It's more common to write to a single log file. And you need to make sure that you flush the output after every write. Otherwise you can lose data. Finally, you should consider wrapping the service in a console application so that you can debug it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517550/wrapping-a-c-sharp-service-in-a-console-app-to-debug-it

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I am going to do that and see. Thanks

Comment: @JimMischel, As you probably know, the OnStart method of a windows service times out, about 30 secs by default. This means that you should not run code in there, just start a thread that will do the work. I got handed this code that had the controller and queue classes but as you suggest I also don't see the reason for the controller, I can just as well run the queueworkItems function from the onstart. I will do that and see. The reason for logging to multiple files is it makes for easier debugging. And Logtofile flushes the output. Thanks