# C# Regex.Split() does not work as expected

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying out services in C#, so I cannot debug values using Console.WriteLine(...). That's why I don't know what is in my variable number at the end:

```
    public int addAndSoustractNumberFromAString(string ustr)
    {
        int result = 0;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            string str = ustr.Trim();

            //Regexes
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex valid_regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[\+]\d+|[\-]\d+");
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex invalid_regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[a-zA-Z]");

            //Handling errors
            if (invalid_regex.IsMatch(str) || !valid_regex.IsMatch(str) || !Char.IsDigit(str[str.Length - 1])) return 0;
            if (Char.IsDigit(str[0])) str = "+" + str;

            //Load all numbers in a string array
            List<string> numbers = new List<string>(valid_regex.Split(str).ToArray());

            //Cast string numbers to int + result calculation
            foreach (string number in numbers) { if (!int.TryParse(number, out int n)) return 99; result += n; }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

**What does my code?**
I enter additions & subtractions, it does the operations & return the result as an integer.

**example:**
If I enter "52-2+3" it should return 53

**Problem:**
My code always returns 99 which means the parsing failed.
Just in case, I tried `int.TryParse("-2", out int n)` instead and it works fine.

**The line that is not working:**

```
List<string> numbers = new List<string>(valid_regex.Split(str).ToArray());
```

My regexes are fine, I tested them with the website `regexstorm net`.

My question is, why my string isn't split correctly using a supposed valid regex? Is Regex.Split() not doing what I believe it does? (I thought it would split my string into +number or -number strings

*Side note: it's ok if it does not start with a sign. If my string starts with a number it will add "+" at the end for regex purposes.*

Comment: Why do you declare an int inside the call to `TryParse` ? Don't you want to get this value ? Have you tried declaring `int n;` then `int.TryParse(number, out n)` ?

Comment: Yeah, it works for my other methodes. Just in case I tested and it still shows 99. It's ok to declare it inside the function TryParse.

Comment: Couldn't you get this code into a Console Application and debug it there?

Comment: People are serious downvoting without saying anything... I tested a lot of things before posting it here... :/

No I can't, it use ISS, Console.WriteLine(...) doesn't work.

Comment: How to debug a Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications - The code you have posted (aside from the origin of the input variable) will behave the same in a console app as it would in a service app, copy paste it into one and you can debug as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll try that out.

Comment: This is probably simpler: [Wrapping a C# service in a console app to debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517550/wrapping-a-c-sharp-service-in-a-console-app-to-debug-it)

Comment: "I cannot debug values using Console.WriteLine" - why not debug it using a debugger then? Its much better than Console.WriteLine anyway...

Comment: There is string in my array numbers and they are all empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Regex is not a Split()ing Regex.

Split() expects the regular expression to define the delimiter (i.e. split on a comma or semicolon).  Your regex describes the values.

It seems like you want the result of Matches() and not Split().

This seems to work for me with your example:

```
List<string> numbers = valid_regex.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

Also, LinqPad is a wonderful tool to prototype code snippets like this one.

Comment: It's working ! So as expected I was misunderstanding the regex.split() function. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your regexp with `([\+\-]\d+)` made the trick with the example `"52-2+3"` [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t8ibAr).

Also added `.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();` after the split so you get rid of empty strings.